# UIPopoverController for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, uipopovercontroller, statusbaritem

Is there any framework available for Mac OS X development that achieves a similar effect as [UIPopoverController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html) for iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for NSPopover, which was introduced in 10.7: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSPopover_Class/Reference/Reference.html